# What word am I thinking?

Tags: riddle

I'm thinking of a word you can spell on one hand.

If you add "e" or ɛ, it might describe the man who lived here:

[image: Image 1]

Add the sound of the world's favorite drink, and you'll find something often worn here:

[image: Image 2]

Add the first 3 letters of this island's mechanical secret, and you'll find a common setting:

[image: Image 3]

Add The One Who Originated and drink some with Coke.
Yes it's spelled wrong but you'll be too gone to notice.

*What is the word and why?*

Hint:

> You want a hint to get you started?? The solution starts with you!

---

Image sources (may make puzzle easier):

> [Image 1](http://cdn.idigitaltimes.com/sites/idigitaltimes.com/files/styles/image_embed/public/2014/11/07/frasier-living-room.jpg?itok=QQKLf-6R) [Image 2](http://garutweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/world-map-outline-black-pjlagxi6.png) [Image 3](http://static.planetminecraft.com/files/resource_media/screenshot/1211/Lincon-Island_1735241.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it:

> Urban

I'm thinking of a word you can spell on one hand.

> 5 letters in urban for 5 fingers on one hand.

If you add "e" or ɛ, it might describe the man who lived here:

> An [urbane](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define+urbane) man would live in that "courteous and refined [...] manner."

Add the sound of the world's favorite drink, and you'll find something often worn here:

> Tea is [the world's favourite drink](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=World%27s+favourite+drink) (after water) and makes a `T` sound (the letter t)
>  T + urban = [Turban](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define+turban)
>  Turbans are worn predominately by Sikhs and Muslims as a religious practice, and [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bc/Muslim_population_map.png) is an image of the Muslim population.

Add the first 3 letters of this island's mechanical secret, and you'll find a common setting.

> A [sub](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define+sub), as in [submarine](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define+submarine). The island uses submarines as a weapon.
>  Sub + urban = [suburban](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define+suburban)
>  The [suburbs](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define+suburb) are common area <sup>[[citation needed]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation_(horse))</sup>.

Add The One Who Originated and drink some with Coke.

> I have no idea. I think "The One Who Originated" would be some religious reference, like Adam or Eve. I also think "[Coke](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define+coke)" refers to [cocaine](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define+cocaine), rather than [the famous carbonated non-alcoholic drink.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define+Coca-Cola) (and, for completion's sake, it's definitely not [coal coke](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define+coal+coke)), as you wouldn't drink something with another drink.
>  
>  Also, should I unhide this as it's not the answer?

The hint:

> > You want a hint to get you started?? The solution starts with you!
>  I think this means it is where I am. Since I am on the internet, I am in an urban area.
>  It may also mean "The solution starts with you" ("u"). Urban starts with "u" ("you").

Comment: Correct for the most part! What does the ɛ refer to? A hint for "The One Who Originated" is that it's musical, not religious.